# Taking the average of the 3 numbers in the array with the pointer

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pointers

```
int main()
{
    float dizi[10], *ptr, ort, toplam = 0.0;
    int i;
    ptr = dizi;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        printf("input %d. value : ", i);
        scanf("%f", &*ptr);
        toplam += *ptr;
    }

    for (i = 4; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        *(ptr + i) = toplam / 3;
        printf("%d. value is : %f\n", i, *(ptr + i));
    }
}
```

The procedure is as follows: For example, the first three values I entered are 2,3,4 and the average of them, '3', is shown as the 4th element of the array. After that, it should take the average of the 2nd, 3rd and 4th values of the array, '3','4','4', and save the number 3.66 as the 5th value of the array. This process should continue until the last element of the array, the 10th value. In short, each element must be calculated as the average of the previous three element values and added to the array sequentially. I need to solve this using pointer.

Comment: `&*ptr` is just `ptr`. And `*(ptr+i) ` is the same as the easier to read `ptr[i]`...

Comment: And C array indexes are 0 based, not 1. You're going off the end of the `dizi` array.

Comment: _"I need to solve this using pointer."_...   Is there a question in there somewhere?  Is there a problem that you can describe?

Comment: There's another major bug in your first loop. Think carefully about what it's doing.

Comment: I'm going to take a test tomorrow and it's a possible question. In the question, it was requested to make a solution with a pointer. Since I think it will be the same in the exam, I am looking for a solution with a pointer.

Comment: Yes but you need to tell us what prevents you from doing it yourself. Since you do have a test tomorrow so presumably you would have studied pointers already. So what specifically do you not understand that you want to ask about? That is, ask a specific question.

Comment: I've worked with pointers and arrays. But I'm still having trouble with questions where pointers and arrays should be used together. For example, in this question, I need to both create an array and process the numbers formed in these arrays with the help of pointers. My biggest problem with the question right now is how do I calculate the average of the 3rd, 4th and 5th elements of the array with a pointer and add the result to the continuation of the array?

Comment: Your first loop tries to read in the values. Did you test that by outputting the 10 values? Did it look as expected?

Comment: I entered the first three values myself from the keyboard and took the 4th value as the average of the numbers I entered. But it shows all the other values of the array as the average of the 3 numbers I entered. For example, let the first three values be 2,3,4. The 4th element of the array shows up as '3' but the rest of the array shows up as '3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not read the second and third numbers into the second and third entries in the array.
- you do not update the sum as you move and compute the next entries.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float dizi[10], *ptr = dizi, sum = 0.0;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        printf("input %d. value: ", i);
        if (scanf("%f", ptr) != 1)
            return 1;
        sum += *ptr;
        ptr++;
    }

    for (i = 4; i <= 10; i++) {
        *ptr = sum / 3;  // store the average
        printf("%d. value is: %g\n", i, *ptr);
        sum -= ptr[-3];  // subtract the first value
        sum += *ptr;     // add the next value
        ptr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
input 1. value: 2
input 2. value: 3
input 3. value: 4
4. value is: 3
5. value is: 3.33333
6. value is: 3.44444
7. value is: 3.25926
8. value is: 3.34568
9. value is: 3.34979
10. value is: 3.31824
```

Comment: You explained it so well, thank you very much.